# How to set format_string dynamically in scope?

Tags: scope, ssas, mdx, format-string, ssas-2008-r2

I have 3 measures:

```
[Measures].[Some Count] with FORMAT_STRING="#,0"
[Measures].[Some Amount] with FORMAT_STRING="Currency"
[Measures].[Some Percent] with FORMAT_STRING="Percent"
```

SCOPE is used to change values of all measures, let's say this way:

```
SCOPE ([Dimension 1].[Hierarchy 1].[Level 1]);
THIS = IIF(<some condition>,<change>,<not change>);
FORMAT_STRING(THIS) = ???
END SCOPE;
```

**Problem**: Measures format is wrong for upper levels of [Dimension 1]. 12345 instead of 12,345 etc.

**Possible solution**: change to IIF(Measures.CurrentMember is [Measures].[Some Count],"#,0" etc.)

Disadvantages:

1. Measures lists creation, its support (if smth is changed, not to forget change here and so on)
2. No opportunity to work with sets of measures (even inside SSAS Browser).

Is there any way to set measures formats dynamically?

**UPDATE**: Actually, there are several hundreds of measures in real project, so I'm trying to avoid lists of measures.

Comment: In general or in FORMAT_STRING(THIS)? It works in regular MDX expressions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want, but you can try to use:

```
FORMAT_STRING([Measures].[Cost])='"£"#,0';
```

after your scope.

Answer (score 0):

You could keep the format in a member attribute and pass it...

```
format_string(this) = (existing [Dimension 1].[Format].[Format]).item(0).membervalue;
```